# Use struct with forward declaratio

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I need to use a struct before it was actually declared, how is that possible ? Thank you.
I need to use C1 before it was declared, but I get incomplete type error.

```
   struct C1;
    
    struct Cap
    {
        C1 l1;
    };
    
    struct C1 : Cap
    {
    };
```

Comment: You cannot. C++ doesn't work this way. You can try and use a pointer, or explain your [real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) problem.

Comment: If `C1` is a `Cap`, that's what `struct C1 : Cap` says, then why does `Cap` need a `C1` member?

Comment: `C1` is a `Cap`, ie it contains a `Cap` sub object, and each `Cap` contains a `C1` and every `C1` contains a `Cap` as sub object and that `Cap` contains a `C1` member, and so on. It isnt a C++ restriction that makes your code not work. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Your code isnt the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `C1` in the `Cap` struct by value as to calculate the size of a `Cap` object would require knowing the size of a `C1`.

You could use it by reference (`C1&`) or pointer (`C1*`) as the size of a pointer is a known size.